# Baking through python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, normals, baking

The script I have now imports an fbx, deletes the existing material and assigns a material that comes with the .blend scene. Then the idea is to bake out the cycles normal after, but I'm getting a context is incorrect error no matter what I try upon baking, everything until that works correctly. Any help is appreciated!

```
import bpy
import time 
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath = "C:/temp/TEMP.fbx")

time.sleep(2)

for ob in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:
    ob.active_material_index = 0
    #bpy.context.active_object= ob
    for i in range(len(ob.material_slots)):
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': ob})

ob = bpy.context.selected_editable_objects[0]

# Get material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Prexisting")


# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    # assign to 1st material slot
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    # no slots
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)


time.sleep(2)
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='NORMAL')
```

Resulting in:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.bake.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```